# Power Query SQL bring in cell contents for the where statement

Tags: sql, power-query, powerpivot, parameters

I am trying to build a flexible sql where statement so that my power query can pull the exact data the user specifies.  I have an excel worksheet with about 18 cells that the user populates.  I use formulas to create the where statement just as I want it in cell C1.  I'd like to run a query in PowerQuery or Power Pivot that will bring the text of that where statement and include it into the ODBC SQL pull.  So far when I search I can see about bringing in one parameter at a time, but I was hoping I could bring in the entire where statement.   Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Generally you have to link together expressions with `and` and `or` if you have criteria for more than one field; alternatively build one long string of all fields and match against that.